# How to run windows commands (cd programfiles..etc) through java program

Tags: java

I want to ask we can run commands in windows like i open the command prompt by typing cmd.
    C:/> cd programFiles
    C:/>cd anydir

I want to ask can i run these commands from java. Like i want to run the command `cd programfiles`through java. can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686005/948268) to a similar question which some people found useful. Here is it:

You can use [Runtime.exec(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.io.File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) where you can set the working directory.

Or else you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class as follows:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException 
{                
    String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "dir"};
    // ProcessBuilder will execute process named 'CMD' and will provide '/C' and 'dir' as command line arguments to 'CMD'

    ProcessBuilder pbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = probuilder.start();

    //Wait for process to finish
    try 
    {            
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);        
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {            
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
}
```

Comment: you used `{"CMD", "/C", "dir"}`. Does cmd stands for command, /C denotes C directory and dir means any directory in the C ?

Comment: Check javadoc for [ProcessBuilder constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder(java.util.List)), index 0 is the program and remaining indexes are it's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change working directory there are built in functions for that. If you want to run commands, see [example](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8)

Answer (score 0):

This is used to run commmand line commands using Java

```
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
```

Comment: This will give you a lot of information regardin how to use this class      http://www.programmingforums.org/post208741.html