# How can I run files in Java?

Tags: java

How can I run a file (like an exe program) using java? I have searched up how to open a file (even on oracle docs) to no avail. Is there a class to help me with this? I tried

```
try 
{     
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;     
Process p => rt.exec("Program.exe") ;     
InputStream in = p.getInputStream() ;    
 OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream ();     
 InputSream err = p.getErrorStream() ; 


p.destroy() ; 
} 
catch(Exception exc) 
{
}
```

But it didn't work

Comment: really ? took like 20 seconds tops to find a relevant tutorial on google

Comment: A good place to start would be [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: See the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685893/run-exe-file-from-java-from-file-location

Comment: @Joao _Should I switch to google?_ depends on your preference. Different search engines use different algorithms, indexing... etc for search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\program files\\test\\test.exe", null, new File("c:\\program files\\test\\"));
```