# Java runtime's .exec() wont open executable

Tags: java

I am trying to execute another file using Runtime and Process

```
try
{
Runtime run =   Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pro =   run.exec("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file.exe");

}
catch(Exception a)
{
    a.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can enter this command in either run or cmd and am able to open the file but running it through my program it won't open. There are no errors, it just doesn't open.

Comment: If there are no errors then it probably runs - how do you know that it doesn't?

Comment: I've tried multiple files

Comment: Instead of Exception use Throwable and see if any exception is thrown

Comment: @M.Sharma `exec` only throws Exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand what is going on (and it is actually a requirement of the Process class), you need to redirect the input and error streams of your process - and using a ProcessBuilder is the recommended way to start processes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file.exe");
    runProcess(pb)
}

private static void runProcess(ProcessBuilder pb) throws IOException {
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: not getting anything printed, could this indicate that it's not reading the file properly?

Comment: @joe reading what file? What is `file.exe` supposed to do? What happens when you run `C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.exe` from the command line?

Comment: It starts a video game, launching from the command line works as it should.

Comment: but i've tried multiple files. launching normal files like "notepad" works fine from the code

Comment: just wont open my exe files from any location

Comment: how do you run it from the command line? Are you in the `C:\Users\user\Desktop` folder then run `file.exe`? What happens if you go to `c:` and run `C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.exe`?

Comment: You can set the working directory with `pb.directory(new File("c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop");` before calling `pb.start();`.

Comment: Alright problem seemed to be in the files themselves and the way I was calling them. Thanks for the replies, all methods worked after I changed the files.

Answer (score 1):

You must do

```
Process pro =   run.exec("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file.exe",null,"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\");
```

Please see [Run .exe file from Java from file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685893/run-exe-file-from-java-from-file-location)

Comment: the 3rd actual parameter is a File which was demonstrated in that example you linked, i followed this and it still wont open.

Comment: Process pro =   run.exec("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file.exe",null,new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop"));

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
  String []cmdarray = new String[4];
  cmdarray[0] = "cmd";
  cmdarray[1] = "/c";
  cmdarray[2] = "start";
  cmdarray[3] = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file.exe";
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, create a batch file ,like start_file.bat.
The content like this:

```
cd C:\Users\user\Desktop ----- Goto this directory
C:   ----- This line is very important
file.exe
```

Both the two approaches work well.

```
  Runtime r  = Runtime.getRuntime();
  String []cmdarray = new String[4];
  cmdarray[0] = "cmd";
  cmdarray[1] = "/c";
  cmdarray[2] = "start";
  cmdarray[3] = "C:/users/desktop/start_file.bat";
  r.exec(cmdarray);
```

And this one:

```
  r.exec("C:/users/desktop/start_file.bat");
  You can read the output from this new process.
```

Comment: Perhaps , windows is aware of LOCATION where the program starts. There are so many  assumptions on root path,such as  environment variables ,where the os can find related dlls..