# How to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to run a program within project?

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

I am new to java (especially exceptions like IO, which might be my problem), and I am having trouble running a .exe file that is located inside a folder in my Java project (A gameboy emulator). Here's what I have so far:

```
try {
            Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("\VBA\VisualBoyAdvance-1.8.0-511.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The folder that VisualBoyAdvance is in is called VBA, every time I run the program, it says that the .exe is not found. How should I be formatting this?

Comment: are u running this on a mac or windows ? if its windows u need to have the drive name specified c:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run .exe file from Java from file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685893/run-exe-file-from-java-from-file-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the folder with file is in project directory, you can get absolute path to your file, like this:

```
String path = new File("VBA/VisualBoyAdvance-1.8.0-511.exe").getAbsolutePath();
```

And then execute using this path:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on windows and the file is in C: drive then try something like this

```
try {
            Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("c:\\VBA\\VisualBoyAdvance-1.8.0-511.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```