# Error with Java.lang.runtime.exec method

Tags: java, directory, apache-poi, runtime, miktex

I'm trying to run MixTex from a Java program, using the runtime.exec method. 
The code is

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("miktex-pdf[--output-directory=(directory)][TestFile.tex]");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CitationMachine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
```

I'm getting an error saying that they can't find the program. I
ve read [Run .exe file in Java from file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685893/run-exe-file-in-java-from-file-location) but don't know how to adapt this to include the options and specify the tex file to be compiled. The documentation for latex command line I want to use is found at https://docs.miktex.org/manual/pdftex.html. Full documentation for other commands is found https://mirrors.sorengard.com/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/doc/2.9/miktex.pdf.

I want to specify the output directory of the file, the directory where the .tex file is located, and the name of the tex file

What am I doing wrong? Can you tell me how to fix my code or what would be a "better" way to run compile a tex document as part of a java program?

I know Apache POI exists, but I don't know how to use it and I'm already familiar with LaTex and know that I should be able to compile a pdf that way.

Comment: The program is *called* "miktex-pdf[--output-directory=(directory)][TestFile.tex]"??? That seems very suspicious.. recheck/share the documentation that shows the posted syntax is valid.

Comment: Can that command work from the command line?  There doesn't appear to be spaces between the command and the parameters.  I would, strongly, recommend using `ProcessBuilder` as it handles the parameters better

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll try that

Comment: @user2864740 I provided the documentation above. Here it is agin: https://docs.miktex.org/manual/pdftex.html I believe I did use correct syntax

Comment: @trumpisterrible Haha. That's the confusion. The `[]`s in the documentation mean the arguments are *optional* - however, they are *not* meant to be included during invocation. Compare with `"miktex-pdftex --output-directory=some_dir TestFile.tex"` (it should be possible to run this successfully *from the command line*, without the quotes of course). Also, see @MadProgrammger's comment. I also changed `miktex-pdf` to `miktex-pdftex` per link.

Comment: @user2864740 This is the answer, so it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am now trying to use process builder  using this code:

Comment: @ MadProgrammer List<String> processes = new ArrayList<String>();
        processes.add("miktex-pdftex --output-directory=E:\\IT Java Assignment\\CitationMachine Works_Cited.tex");
        ProcessBuilder build = new ProcessBuilder(processes);

Comment: @MadProgrammer this is based off of the same documentation for LaTex pdftex provided above

Comment: @trumpisterrible Each command/parameter in the `List` should be it's own element, this way, you get over the issue if spaces in the command line/parameters

Comment: @MadProgrammer The commands are in their own lines in Netbeans. That is simply how it copied

Comment: @MadProgrammer To have the processes in the Process builder run, do I type start(build); ? Or is there a different way I'm supposed to run all of the programs in Process builder?

Comment: @trumpisterrible `processes.add("miktex-pdftex --output-directory=E:\\IT Java Assignment\\CitationMachine Works_Cited.tex")` is placing the command and all the parameters into a single element

Comment: @MadProgrammer What is the significance of putting the command and all of its parameters into a single element? This isn't answering my wuestion of how to get 'miktex-pdftex --output-directory...' to run. How do I do this? I can't find any  examples in English on youtube

Comment: @trumpisterrible As I said, using `ProcessBuilder` and placing each command/parameter into the command `List` as separate elements removes the need to deal with spaces in individual parameters (like paths).  `ProcessBuilder` also provide additional configuration which can make executing external process simpler

Comment: @MadProgrammer The processes in the process builder won't run after I've added them to it.   I;ve started a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483015/ive-already-created-a-process-builder-how-do-i-run-all-of-the-programs-in-the . Since you were teh person who reccomended Process Builder to me (and understand it well) It would be appreciated if you can continue helping me get the process to run. So please reply on the new question's page