# how to run another programm before run .jar

Tags: java, jar, xampp

I am making a Java app with a local database in localhost. Now, I want to make an executable program from my .jar but I want the user that will use my app, no need to open the xampp and turn on the mySQL module. I mean, if the user open the .exe, it will open the xampp and turn on the module, then the .jar will pop out. so its more simple for the user. any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 options for your case:

1 - you can use batch/shell script before run the your jar file

2 - if you have java source code, you also call another program in your code before build a jar file. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685893/run-exe-file-in-java-from-file-location)